# Contract not getting listen on opensea mainnet, however shows NFTs in metamask & works on testnet

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, opensea

Just as the title says, on opensea testnets mumbai and ropsten, it 'imports' the smart contract to create the collection, however on the polygon mainnet, the same contracts are working perfectly.
The NFTs even show in my wallet on the mainnet, the contract is verified on etherscan & I can mint.
Please check https://polygonscan.com/address/0xb6AF03FE32Ac3DffDd4F2661270DFEE00C15c3d9

Is there anything special I have to do for the mainnet opensea to accept my smart contract?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I created a new smart contract and added

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC721/IERC721Upgradeable.sol";
```

Now it seems to work, still, I fail to understand why on the testnet opensea, it worked without it...
Sometimes development makes no sense.

Comment: This helped me too, after several hours of debugging. Thanks a lot!! I sure would like to understand why it helps.